# Windows Phone 8.1 - custom Pivot header

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

So I'm trying to recreate a custom Pivot project from 8.0, [seen here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tabbed_interface_with_Pivot_animation_for_Windows_Phone). 
I've looked at many places, but can't seem to find an answer.

My goal is to create a Pivot control, which has a header area similar to Android's TabbedPage - fixed, non-automatically-moving headers on top, which can be scrolled sideways.

For now I'd be happy if I could have fixed 3-4 tabs on top, with selection coloring, and having it non-scrolling with the content.

Any idea on how to achieve this? I haven't got too much experience in custom styling WP8.1 elements to such extent.

Comment: Are you talking about the XAML or WinJS Pivot control? Don't know about the XAML but I know there's not much you can do to customize the WinJS control. But, you can create such a control yourself faking tabs and hiding and showing content depending on the selected "tab"

Comment: XAML control. In WinJS you can do it, I have seen it done to the Pivot control. For that, check out the WP app "Yodel" (YikYak client).

Comment: really? is that the pivot control? they changed it a lot

Comment: This question is tagged wp8.1 but not what XAML language... are we talking Silverlight or WinRT?